# Does Android debug.keystore SHA1 is same for all?

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-install-apk

debug.keystore is generated automatically when we install our android sdk. So does our debug.keystore will have same SHA1 in all machines?

Comment: yes @arunrk it is same for that system

Comment: You can use the same debug keystore for all apps. But obviously the release would be different

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't have a same debug key for each machine. And you won't have a same debug key for a machine because there is [an expiry for the debug key](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#expdebug):

> The self-signed certificate used to sign your APK for debugging has an
>   expiration date of 365 days from its creation date. When the
>   certificate expires, you will get a build error.
>
> To fix this problem, simply delete the **debug.keystore** file. The file
>   is stored in the following locations:
>
> - ~/.android/ on OS X and Linux
> - C:\Documents and
>     Settings\.android\ on Windows XP
> - C:\Users\.android\ on
>     Windows Vista and Windows 7, 8, and 10
>
> The next time you build and run
>   the debug build type, the build tools will regenerate a new keystore
>   and debug key. Note that you must run your app, building alone does
>   not regenerate the keystore and debug key.

There's possibility that you'll get the same debug key before the expiration date, but don't depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not same for all. It will same for particular system.